# How do I style selected item on List with GenericListCellRenderer?

Tags: codenameone

I have created a UI using a CN1 list. I user the GenericListCellRenderer because each list item is rendered using a custom component. Everything else works fine except I can not seem to find a way of styling the selected list item so that it renders using a different style.

I have tried styling the components that I pass to the setRenderer method as shown below:

```
list.setRenderer(new GenericListCellRenderer(contSelected, contUnSelected));
```

But this is not working. I also want to be able to change the default colors on the pressed event, as it is currently showing a white background with an underline

I need too be able to do the following:

1) Style the different components that make up the selected item ui.
2) Style the item selected / pressed event, or disable the pressed event altogether as I am using the selection listener.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your list renderer uiid is named `MyUiid` for example, just add another uiid named `MyUiidSelected` and style it to match your selected state.

Comment: My data model is a HashMap

`Map<String, Object> accountMap = new HashMap<>();
            accountMap.put("accNo", acc.accNo.get());
            accountMap.put("accNo_uiid", "AccountNo");
     ....`

Comment: My data model is a HashMap

`Map<String, Object> accountMap = new HashMap<>();
            accountMap.put("accNo", acc.accNo.get());
            accountMap.put("accNo_uiid", "AccountNo");
     ....`
And my Renderer is a Container with a whole bunch of Labels and other components, all differently styled. The unselected state is styled using the UIIDs as defined in the model e.g. I have a css entry for AccountNo

How do I attach the selected Uiid to the components of the renderer, or do I even need to do that?

Comment: If you base your Uiids on HashMap values, just take those values and concatenate them with "Selected" to create the selected state.

Comment: I would **strongly** suggest avoiding lists and using containers see this https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---create-a-list-of-items-the-easy-way.html and this http://www.codenameone.com/blog/avoiding-lists.html